# Bootstrap Tabs - Next and Previous Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have the following: http://goo.gl/FZMd33

My desired output would be if the first tab is selected, the previous button becomes disabled and at the other end when the last tab is selected the next tab becomes disabled.

Also as a separate thought I would also like to achieve the Next button show the first tab if the last tab is currently selected and the opposite with the Previous button on first tab to show last tab on click

Comment: what specific problems are you facing ? What did you try ?

Comment: Unfortunatly it didnt help, but thanks very much. I have found a plugin that has done it for me http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code

```
//Put this code on click of **Next Button**

        if ($tabs.filter('.active').next('li').length > 0) {
             $('#wheel-right').removeAttr("disabled");
         } else {
             $('#wheel-right').attr("disabled", "disabled");
         }




// Put this code on click  of **Previous Button**

     if ($tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').length > 0) {
         $('#wheel-left').removeAttr("disabled");
     } else {
         $('#wheel-left').attr("disabled", "disabled");
     }
```